# Detecting collision between circle and square

Tags: javascript, math, geometry, html5-canvas, collision-detection

I know this has been asked a lot, but personally, i couldn't find a suitable answer. Pretty much everywhere, the function looks something like:

```
function rccol(rect, circle){
    var dx = Math.abs(circle.x - (rect.x + rect.width / 2));
    var dy = Math.abs(circle.y - (rect.y + rect.height / 2));

    if(dx > circle.radius + rect.width / 2) return false;
    if(dy > circle.radius + rect.height / 2) return false;

    if(dx <= rect.width) return true;
    if(dy <= rect.height) return true; 

    var dx = dx - rect.width;
    var dy = dy - rect.height
    return((dx * dx + dy * dy) <= (circle.radius * circle.radius));
}
```

And that works perfectly. The issue is that I'm using it for collision detection in a game, where the circle is the player's collision box, and the square is let's say a wall. I need to be able to determine where the contact occurred so that i can actually prevent the "player" from going into the "wall" so the simple boolean that gets returned, doesn't really work in my use-case.

Answer (score 0):

Having circle center coordinates `(cx, cy)`, you can calculate squared distance from circle center to rectangle.

```
dx = Max(Abs(cx - rect.center.x) - rect.width / 2, 0)
dy = Max(Abs(cy - rect.center.y) - rect.height / 2, 0)
SquaredDistance = dx * dx + dy * dy
```

When circle is outside of rectangle initially, it is possible to remove `Max` call.

```
dx = Abs(cx - rect.center.x) - rect.width / 2
dy = Abs(cy - rect.center.y) - rect.height / 2
```

Also we can remove `Abs` for known initial position (note - upto moment of sign change!)

```
if cx >= rect.center.x:
      dx = cx - rect.center.x - rect.width / 2
else:
      dx =  - cx + rect.center.x - rect.width / 2
```

To avoid a lot od different cases, we can  virtually put player in the first quadrant relative to rectangle center and correspondingly change coordinates and velocity components

```
if cx0 < 0:
   cx0 = - cx0
   vx = -vx
if cy0 < 0:
   cy0 = - cy0
   vy = -vy
```

To register collision moment, you have to substitute coordinates with parametric equations using start point and velocity vector components `(vx, vy)`

```
cx = cx0 + vx * t
cy = cy0 + vy * t
```

and solve (quadratic) equation for `t`

```
SquaredDistance - Radius^2 = 0

(cx0 + vx * t - rect.center.x - rect.width/2)^2 + 
(cy0 + vy * t - rect.center.y - rect.height/2)^2 - 
Radius^2 = 0
```

Ater that you can get zero (no collision), one (touch event) or two roots (moment of collision and moment of exit).

Comment: The thing is, currently the "Player" or the circle object does not have a variable for a velocity, as it travels at a fixed speed..

Comment: Player definitely has velocity components ;) How is his movement described? With speed and angle?

Comment: For now, just adding a "speed" value to the x and y cordinates based on the user inuput

Comment: if position changes as  `x += vx` on timer, then `vx` is x-component of velocity

Comment: huh.. yeah, but I'm having a bit of trouble understanding how exactly to implement this..

Comment: Values and ratio of addends vx and vy define speed and direction of moving. You can substirute starting coordinates and these components into equation and get quadratic equation.

Comment: no, i got that part down, what i meant is actually *using* the equations to get the side of impact, maybe i'm just not understanding the examples.. I'm fairly new to this type of stuff, and i need more "in-depth" explanations, sorry!

Comment: I addes some explanations

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227801/discussion-between-kriskotoo-bg-and-mbo).